# How to test unicorn.rb

Tags: ruby, unicorn

I've actually been Unicorn for a few years now, but I've never really run any proper tests on my basic code for running a Unicorn application. So one of the first things I want to test is `unicorn.rb`. At the very least, I'd like to make sure it compiles, but, of course,  I want to eventually run more detailed tests on it.

But I can't figure out how to load the file. Obviously just running it from the command line doesn't accomplish anything. I'd like to run the code in the file without having to run Unicorn itself. That is, I want to do some basic unit testing before going much further with my application.

So the question is how do I load and run `unicorn.rb` by itself, with minimal extra required code.

If you're interested, here's my current `unicorn.rb`. I welcome your feedback, but my main goal right now is to find a way to run tests on just that file.

```rb
# Snout is a tiny application for experimenting with Unicorn.
# Nothing more, nothing less.

# path to data directory
snout_data_root = '/srv/apps/snout'

# path to app that will be used to configure unicorn
@dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# workers
worker_processes 5
working_directory @dir

# timeout
timeout 30

# set user and group
user 'www-data', 'www-data'

# Specify path to socket unicorn listens to
listen "#{snout_data_root}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Set process id path
pid "#{snout_data_root}/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Not exactly sure what this does, but the following page suggests it's
# generally a good idea to have this setting.
# https://bogomips.org/unicorn/Unicorn/Configurator.html
rewindable_input false

# avoid spawn loops
preload_app true

# paths to which Unicorn sends STDOUT and STDERR
stderr_path "#{snout_data_root}/logs/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{snout_data_root}/logs/unicorn.log"
```

Comment: I would not recommend that you write tests for code that you don't own. You didn't write unicorn and you don't maintain unicorn so why write tests for unicorn? What do you stand to gain by writing a test suite for software already covered by the unicorn test suite?

Comment: I'm not testing Unicorn. I'm testing my own script, unicorn.rb.

Comment: That isn't your own code. Those are *arguments* to unicorn's code. It's the equivalent of saying "I want to test `User.find(1)` in ActiveRecord." Why? `find` is already covered by the AR test suite. Likewise `timeout` and `working_directory` are already covered by the unicorn test suite.

Comment: I know I should probably let this go but I'm really curious. I wrote that code. The file is on my server. I kinda thought that meant that it's my code. Whose code is it?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/d947cb91cf9dbd65d48e497b2605b124571f77ad/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb). That's where all the methods are defined, e.g., `def worker_processes(nr); set_int(:worker_processes, nr, 1); end`. You didn't define the methods, you are calling methods defined in the Unicorn gem and passing your custom arguments. `unicorn.rb` is the equivalent of an ini file or other config file. There's no actual code, it's just a set of options you're defining. "Your code" would be if you included some logic, e.g.,

Comment: let’s pretend that you need different values for different environments, if you defined a method in this file as `def process_count_for(env_name); env_name == 'production' ? 5 : 1; end` and you called that method with `worker_processes(process_count_for(ENV['RACK_ENV']))` rather than just directly calling `worker_processes 5` then *that* would be something you could test. But the test would not be “*did it spawn 5 workers?*", the test would be “*did it return 5 or 1?*” because that’s what *your code* is doing. Does that make sense?

Comment: And honestly, there's no reason to let it go if you think I'm wrong or if you want to understand this explanation better. I'm happy to continue the discussion if you'd like.

Comment: First, apologies for being snarky. You're being very friendly and helpful. I just want to test some basic stuff in the file. For example, I set snout_data_root to a path. I want to test that that path actually exists. I want to test that preload_app is set to true. These files will be generated programmatically so I want to test what is generated.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! If you have code that generates `unicorn.rb` and you want to test whether or not the generated file contains the data that you expect then there are two paths: the first is to test *side-effects*, e.g., *does the server run with preload_app set to true?*; the second is to check the generated file to ensure its contents are what you expect. The first is very difficult and cumbersome. The second is easy: slurp the file before you add `preload_app true` and verify the line doesn't exist, then add the line, then slurp the file again and verify the line exists.

Comment: In other words, test the output of the generator, don't test the behavior of Unicorn when it uses the generated file.